# Insert content to the beginning of every page for a user defined page range

Tags: shipout

I want to insert some content (in my case a table) to the beginning of every page. Furthermore I want to set two "markers" in the document such that it is printed only on the beginning of every page between the markers (in particular I want to be able to omit it on the first page).

Here is some pseudocode as it might work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\small Header} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\small Header} 
\fancyhead[L]{\small Header}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}


%\AtBeginDocument{
\AtEveryPageFromMarkerAtoB{
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,width=\linewidth,colspec={XXX}}
A table & containing & some stuff \\
large enough & not to fit & into \\
a header & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

%% On the first page the header should be ommitted, or more general it should start on the page with marker A
\lipsum

\markerA

\newpage
%% From here on, the table should be inserted automatically to the beginning of every page

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

%% From now on the table should be ommited. 
\markerB

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Not that I only included the explicit `\newpage` commands to create an example. It should work whether I explicitly insert a new page or if it is generated automatically

Comment: If you know how much space to reserve, you can use flowfram to select the page range, reduce the text area (flow frame) and put the table in a static frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hooks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\small Header} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\small Header} 
\fancyhead[L]{\small Header}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}




\begin{document}

%% On the first page the header should be ommitted, or more general it should start on the page with marker A
\lipsum

\AddToHook{shipout/before}[foo]{
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,width=\linewidth,colspec={XXX}}
A table & containing & some stuff \\
large enough & not to fit & into \\
a header & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
}

\newpage
%% From here on, the table should be inserted automatically to the beginning of every page

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[foo]

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```